# PDO ERROR (too many clients already)

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

**SOLVED** *by adding if statement before* `new PDO...`

***DB - POSTGRESQL***

Hi, i have a cycle, that connects to db in every loop with this function:

```
class mypdo
{
    public function open()
    {
        if(!isset($this->VK_DBH))
        {
            $this->VK_DBH = new PDO("pgsql:host={$this->DB_HOST};port=5432;dbname={$this->DB_NAME}", "{$this->DB_USER}", "{$this->DB_PASS}");  
            $this->VK_DBH->query("set names utf8");
            $this->VK_DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); 
        }
    }
    ....
```

At the end of the cycle, connection closes with this function:

```
    ....
    public function close()
    {
        $this->VK_DBH = null;
    }
}
```

So i have something like this:

```
<?php
    $pdo = new mypdo();
    for($i = 0; $i < 300; ++$i)
    {
        $mypdo->open();
        //some other code
        $mypdo->close();
    }
```

And i obtain an exception **SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: sorry, too many clients already**  ~ on 80-90 step of cycle.
Why it appears? Or how to close connection to db properly?

**Dont advice me please to open connection once before cycle**, because i want to understand why i have many connections, if i close each of them in each iteration by `$this->VK_DBH = null;`.

From docs: *To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object.*

http://php.net//manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Why are you mandating a new connection in every iteration? What problem is that solving?

Comment: what is PDO::open_connection and PDO::close_connection ? I'm not familiar with either function.

Comment: Sorry it was some misprints, i edit my post. I dont need to create new connection i every iteration actually, but i want to understand why i have many connections, if i close each of them in each iteration by function `$this->VK_DBH = null;`. From docs: **To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the object.** http://php.net//manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: @Clive i update my question, hope its clearly now

Comment: Your class appears to extend PDO by both inheritance (`extends`) and delegation (the VK_DBH member). Is that really the case? And does that mean you have a call to `parent:__construct` in your constructor, which also opens a DB connection? If possible, could you create a test case that is fully runnable code, rather than fragments which may be missing details such as this?

Comment: @IMSoP no, it's not a problem, i remove 'extends' and nothing changes. **FATAL...**

Comment: At the moment, you're letting us do a lot of guessing about code we can't see, but which might be causing the problem. Could you come up with some code that shows the error, but with nothing hidden from us behind "..." or "more code here". Take a look at [the help article on creating a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @IMSoP thank you, when i wrote example code for you i just add if statement (have edit my post with description) and solve my problem =)  Sorry for bad question, i'm a novice at stackoverflow

Comment: No problem, sometimes trying to create a test case that demonstrates the problem in isolation reveals a lot about what code is actually responsible.